# CMake configure error ：No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found

Tags: cmake

I want to use CMake to generate vs2012 project for vosm.
I downloaded cmake-3.2.3-win32-x86.exe from the Cmake website and installed it.
Then I started Cmake(gui),selected source path and output path and clicked "Configure" but there was an error.

The log shows:
The C compiler identification is unknown

The CXX compiler identification is unknown

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (project):
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

I know little about Cmake. Did I miss anything? I'm really confused because I just followed the steps of others.

Comment: Cmake is just a build configuration utility, you still need a C (and probably a C++) compiler, which either you don't have (you have VS2012 installed though?), or Cmake simply fails to locate.

Comment: Yes，I already have vs2012 installed.How can Cmake locate it?Is there any configuration I need to do? @Siguza